# How can I get the return value from a function calling another function in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

So you can assign a value to `var doub` as below:

```
function getDouble(number) {
    var doubl = number + number;
    return doubl;
}

var num = 4;
var doub = getDouble(num);
```

I want to know if I can get the return type by calling a second function as below. So can the return value of the second method be assigned to `doub`?

```
function getDouble(number) {
    var doubl = number + number;
    return quadruple(doubl);
}

function quadruple(doubl) {
    quad = doubl + doubl
    return quad;
}

var num = 4;
var doub = getDouble(num);
```

For some reason it doesn't work for me.

This is my code with the problem..I am doing something similar to the above, but not working:

In my doc ready, I have this code..I want the result to be stored in **newjsn**

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
     var newjsn= DatabaseCategoriesToSelectList(num, 200, 100);
```

My DatabaseCategoriesToSelectList function is :

```
function DatabaseCategoriesToSelectList(jsn, max, min){

    var ddl="<option selected='selected' value='"+min+"'>Select...</option>";

    //load categories from database, and put them into the select drop down.
    $.getJSON(GLOBALURL+'content/plugins/subcategories/getSubcategories.php',             
        function(data, ddl) {

            var datas=  jQuery.grep(data, function(element, index){
                return element.category_id < max && element.category_id>min; // retain appropriate elements
            });
            for (x=0; x<datas.length; x++){
                ddl= ddl+"<option value='"+datas[x].category_id+"'data-subcategory='"+datas[x].category_subselect+"'>"+datas[x].category_safe_name+"</option>";
            }   
            alert (ddl); return runafter(ddl, jsn); 
        });

}

function runafter(ddl, jsn){
    jsn=ddl;
    alert(jsn);

    return 500;

}
```

For some reason, the alerts work, but I can't get it to return me the string. I even tried to return a random value of 500, and it doesnt..

Comment: This works fine for me. How are you running it?

Comment: thanks, well that is a simple version of what I have..I will add my code to it now

Comment: `quad = doubl + doubl` -> `var quad = doubl + doubl;`

Comment: @AaronLS That won't change the value of the answer, it'll just pollute the globals with a `quad` variable.

Comment: Functionally the code looks fine, but as @AaronLS said you should add 'var' to the declaration to prevent it from being defined as a global variable, and while not strictly required in JS, you should always end your statements with a semicolon.

Comment: @Xymostech Very true, based on what we can see.  Not sure how he's testing it, but an unintentional global var could lead to some wierdness.

Comment: I've realised this may not have been my problem, I've added my actual code I was having the problem with to the bottom of the example I provided

Comment: do you get this alert `alert (ddl)` before this line `return runafter(ddl, jsn);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to have access to the return from a getJson handler.  The framework calls that handler.  You are giving it a function, and .getJson calls that function if/when the response is received.  If you need access to the return of runAfter, you need to do whatever with it you plan to.

Instead of:

```
$.getJSON(GLOBALURL+'content/plugins/subcategories/getSubcategories.php',
  function(data, ddl) {

          ...
           return runafter(ddl, jsn); 
  });
}
```

You need to decide what you want to do with that value, for example I stuff it into the value of some hidden field maybe:

```
$.getJSON(GLOBALURL+'content/plugins/subcategories/getSubcategories.php',
  function(data, ddl) {

          ...
          $('#someField').val( runafter(ddl, jsn) ); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're never returning out of your `DatabaseCategoriesToSelectList` function. Your function looks like this:

```
function DatabaseCategoriesToSelectList(jsn, max, min) {
    ...
    $.getJSON(GLOBALURL+'content/plugins/subcategories/getSubcategories.php',             
        function(data, ddl) {
             ...
             return runafter(ddl, jsn); 
        }
    );
}
```

The inner `return` is not returning out of `DatabaseCategoriesToSelectList`, it is returning out of the inner function. However, there is no way to make this return the values that you want no matter what you do, because `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call. You have to put something like

```
function(data, dll) {
    ...
    var newjsn = runafter(ddl, jsn);
    // put the rest of your stuff that uses newjsn here
}
```

in your code, and then put whatever came after that also into that function also.

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4keHn/)  (*output is : 16*)

What you are doing is just fine *as it should*

```
 function getDouble (number){
    var doubl = number+number;
    return quadruple(doubl);
    }

function quadruple(doubl){
var quad=doubl+doubl
return quad;
}

var num = 4;
var doub = getDouble(num);
```